# Discord.net C# | Downloading Users seemingly not working correctly

Tags: c#, discord.net

My Program doesnt seem to download users correctly. "AlwaysDownloadUsers = true" is added in the config but it doesnt seem to be working correctly. When starting the bot not all users seem to be download because the program always returns "User not Found" until the user starts typing or sends a message...

I think that my code in general is bad, as i used a few sources/tutorials and mixed the code together, so id be happy about every sort of feedback :)

Main Program:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        public DiscordSocketClient _client;
        public CommandService _command;
        public LoggingService _log;
        public CommandHandler _handler;

        public async Task MainAsync()
        {
            var config = new DiscordSocketConfig
            {
                LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug,
                AlwaysDownloadUsers = true,
                MessageCacheSize = 100
            };
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient(config);

            _command = new CommandService();
            _log = new LoggingService(_client, _command);
            _handler = new CommandHandler(_client, _command);

            var token = File.ReadAllText("token.txt");
            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
            await _client.StartAsync();

            _client.Ready += Ready;

            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        public async Task Ready()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bot is Ready!");
            await _handler.InstallCommandsAsync();
        }
    }
```

CommandHandler:

```
public class CommandHandler
{
    private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private readonly CommandService _command;

    public CommandHandler(DiscordSocketClient client, CommandService command)
    {
        _client = client;
        _command = command;
    }

    public async Task InstallCommandsAsync()
    {
        _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
        await _command.AddModulesAsync(assembly: Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), services: null);
    }

    private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage arg)
    {
        var msg = arg as SocketUserMessage;
        if (msg == null) return;

        int argPos = 0;

        if (msg.HasCharPrefix('.', ref argPos) && !(msg.Author.IsBot))
        {
            var _context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, msg);
            var result = await _command.ExecuteAsync(_context, argPos, services: null);

            if (!result.IsSuccess)
                Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorReason);
            if (result.Error.Equals(CommandError.UnmetPrecondition))
                await msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result.ErrorReason);
        }
    }
}
```

Command Class not included as im pretty sure its not at fault

Comment: You need enable member intents in the Discord portal and specify the member intents in the DiscordSocketConfig as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Member intents in the developer portal were enabled already, but not in the DiscordSocketConfig

So i added "Gateway.Intents = GatewayIntents.All" ot the config and its working now

Not working:

```
var config = new DiscordSocketConfig
{
    LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug,
    AlwaysDownloadUsers = true,
    MessageCacheSize = 100,
};
```

Working now:

```
var config = new DiscordSocketConfig
{
    LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug,
    AlwaysDownloadUsers = true,
    MessageCacheSize = 100,
    GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.All
};
```

Thanks Anu6is

Comment: You shouldn't use all if you aren't using all intents. Consider which intents you bot actually requires and set those.